# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Data is not mapped [from Data]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve xml from the database after serializing it and this is the endpoint from the controller snippets

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Data> getAll() {

        List<Data> listOfCountries = oService.getAll();
        return listOfCountries;
    }
```

this is the snippet of code from DAO class

```
public List<Data> getAll() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Data> countryList = session.createQuery("from Data").list();
        return countryList;
    }
```

this is the model class that appears not to be mapped

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Data")
@Entity
@Table(name="Data")
public class Data{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private
    String phone;   

    @Column(name="counter")
    private
    String counter; 

    @Column(name="STREET_NAME")
    private
    String STREET_NAME; 

    @Column(name="address")
```

I added this annotation mapping in the spring config xml file as shown

```
<annotation-driven />
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>org.model.Data</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
```

on access the endpoint I am getting this error

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Data is not mapped [from Data]
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
```

after debugging every layer of my code I found no loop hole that could be a possible fix. Please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you should cast the result by `List<Data>` like this:-

```
List<Data> result = (List<Data>) session.createQuery("from Data").list();
```

or you can also use `entityManager` for create query.

```
Query query = entityManager. createQuery("Select data from Data data");
```